# kotlin java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

Tags: android, kotlin

```
if (aa.isNullOrBlank() || aa.isEmpty() || aa.isNullOrEmpty()) {//to check null
} else {
    someVar = aa.toInt()
    //here error is showing java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before casting into Integer, you have to check if there are only digits.
By `isDigitsOnly()`

```
if (aa.isNullOrBlank() || 
    aa.isEmpty() || 
    aa.isNullOrEmpty() ||  
    !aa.isDigitsOnly() ||
    aa.toIntOrNull() == null
) {
//to check null
} else {
    arra[i][j] = aa.toInt()
}
```

Comment: thank you so much was stuck on the problem for about an hour